# Tinymce - responsive file manager: erro undefined "defaultView" na versão jQ 1.6

Tags: jquery, tinymce-4

Quando eu tento inserir um arquivo ele não abre a janela de gerenciamento de arquivos e da o erro: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei executalo com o jquery 2.1.4 mais nao aceita dentro do noConflict()

estrutura usa:

```
<script src="application/modules/documentos/js/jquery-1.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

pagina:

```
<script src="application/modules/documentos/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="application/modules/documentos/js/tinymce.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $v2 = $.noConflict(true);           

    })
 ...
(function ($) {

   tinymce.execCommand("mceRemoveEditor", true, 'doc-corpo');
            tinymce.init({
                selector: ".doc-tinymce",
                theme: "modern",
                language: "pt_BR",            
                entity_encoding: "raw",
                plugins: [
                "advlist autolink autoresize link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
                "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
                "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor responsivefilemanager"
                ],
                external_filemanager_path:"application/modules/documentos/js/tinymce/plugins/responsivefilemanager/filemanager/",
                filemanager_title:"Gerenciador de arquivos" ,
                external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "plugins/responsivefilemanager/filemanager/plugin.min.js"},
                relative_urls: false,
                remove_script_host: false,
                autoresize_min_height: 0,
                autoresize_max_height: 3000,
                toolbar: "undo redo styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | forecolor backcolor | hr link image | insertdatetime emoticons responsivefilemanager |"


            });


}($v2));

</script>
```